# Parent Refresh - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I use the below JS to refresh Parent page, but I am getting the below message

Code:

```
 window.opener.document.location.reload(); 
 window.close();
```

Please help me how to avoid this

[image]

Comment: Try `window.opener.document.location = window.opener.document.location;`

Comment: This means the original page was loaded via a POST request so you get the warnign when you try to refresh

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid using `POST` before refresh is required or set the location property instead of using `reload`:

```
window.opener.document.location = window.opener.document.location;
```

One more option is to redirect the parent page directly after the `post` request is done. After that the child can refresh the page without the popup.